# Passing values from UITableView to UIView in table header

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

My CoreData model drives series of UITableViewControllers.

One of the detail tables has a header that contains a UIView "GraphView" that uses data from the rows of the table. (It's like iTunes having a custom header to chart song length in a given playlist.) My "playlist" populates from CoreData correctly. But how do I pass data from the TableView to the UIView in its header?

It seems wasteful and redundant to fetch and parse it again, especially when the data is sitting in a convenient mutable array called "steps". Can I just pass the mutable array to the UIView in the header? If so, how?

I've tried creating an NSArray property in the UIView's class called "passedStepsArray", and then setting it from the StepDetailViewController like so:

```
        graphView.passedStepsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:steps copyItems:YES];
```

But back in the GraphView class, it remains NULL. No value gets passed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From my visualization of the problem, it seems you are on the right tracks by having an NSArray property in the GraphView.  You probably don't need to copy the existing array using the `initWithArray:copyItems:` method, just pass a non-mutable copy of the populated steps array:

```
graphView.passedStepsArray = [[steps copy] autorelease];
```

This is assuming that the graphView `passedStepsArray` property is set to retain. (Then don't forget to set `self.passedStepsArray = nil;` in the graphView dealloc methood.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and correct answer... when I put in your code, it still didn't work. But after a few more hours of hair pulling and adding (bad) code to fix (working) code, I realized that my GraphView was not hooked up correctly as an IBOutlet in IB.